Continuous Local Martingales
Let $T^n$ be increasing stopping times such that $T^n \rightarrow \infty$ and let $M$ be a process such that $M_{T^n} \in \mathcal{M}_{\text{loc}}^c$ for all $n$. Show that $M \in \mathcal{M}_{\text{loc}}^c$.
Attempt : Let's define
$$\tau_n := inf\{t>0; |M_t|\ge n\}$$
Since $M_{T^n}$ is a continuous local martingale, $\tau_n$ is increasing to infinity.
Hence, we only need to show that $M_{min(t,T,\tau_n)}$ is a martingale. Any help with that please?
